# Insufficient privilege for read only transaction

Tags: oracle, permissions, transaction

I am using Oracle and SQL Developer and here is a problem I ran into. I have created a table called T_TEST and I am trying to create a read only transaction to it from another user. This is my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE reader
AS
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY;
    SELECT SUM(value) FROM SYSTEM.T_TEST;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

And this is the result that I get:

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

The user itself has this privileges:

```
GRANT CONNECT TO admin1;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO admin1;
GRANT SELECT ON T_TEST TO admin1;
```

Which is enough for this query to work:

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM SYSTEM.T_TEST;
```

However, when I wrap it up in a transaction, as I showed, it fails. So what privileges am I lacking here?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, even after fixing the PL/SQL syntax and granting `create procedure` to admin1. Also, `SELECT` privilege allows `select for update`, which `READ` privilege does not.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `REFERENCES` constraint.

`grant references on system.t_test to admin1`

Also, you shouldn't create tables under `SYSTEM`

Comment: Could you please clarify where exactly should I have the `REFERENCES` constraint?